# Можно ли концерт исполнить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Правильно ли написать: *"25 мая 2017 года в Музее В. А. Тропинина и московских художников его времени с большим успехом прошёл концерт "Огонь любви" в исполнении виртуоза гитарной музыки, которому рукоплескали залы России, Европы и Америки, лауреата международных конкурсов Олега Иванова"*?
Концерт может быть в чьём-то исполнении?

Answer (score 2):

Концерт можно исполнить как **произведение** (напр. Первый концерт Чайковского), можно "исполнить" концертную программу (она состоит из музыкальных произведений). Как **мероприятие** может пройти "*концерт музыки такой-то в исполнении того-то*", но здесь "исполнение" относится уже не к "концерту" (он в значении мероприятия), а к "музыке". Соответственно, в исходном предложении просматривается некоторая стилистическая *небрежность*: поскольку концерт "прошёл", то он назван в значении "мероприятия", которое нельзя "исполнить" - музыка или произведение, к которым могло бы относиться "исполнение", остались за кадром, в мыслях говорившего или писавшего.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант:

25 мая 2017 года в Музее В.А.Тропинина и московских художников его времени с большим успехом прошёл концерт "Огонь любви" **с участием виртуоза** гитарной музыки... Олега Иванова.

КОНЦЕРТ, -а; м. [франц. concert] 1. **Публичное исполнение музыкальных произведений** и других номеров по определённой программе. Симфонический, вокальный, эстрадный к. Праздничный к. Сольный к. Дать к. Выступать с концертами. Выступать, участвовать в концерте. Мы сегодня идём на к.2. **Крупное музыкальное произведение** для сольного инструмента в сопровождении оркестра. К. для фортепиано с оркестром.

Как мы видим, слово концерт — это уже **исполнение**, поэтому повторять его не стоит.

Comment: Примерно с 16 века в Европе существует КОНЦЕРТ как  жанр музыкального произведения, который развивался и видоизменялся.В русской классической музыке жанр инструментального концерта получил своеобразное и глубоко национальное претворение в фортепьянных концертах Чайковского и С.В. Рахманинова, в скрипичных концертах А.К. Глазунова и П.И. Чайковского. Стало быть, концерты исполняют и коллективы, и солисты.

Comment: Речь в вопросе идет о первом значении слова "концерт" (исполнение музыкальных номеров по программе), это нарицательное существительное,  а Вы говорите о  втором значении слова. Но  уже был ответ, что концерт как произведение (напр. Первый концерт Чайковского) именно исполняется. Здесь "концерт" входит в состав имени собственного.

Comment: Верно, не дочитал абзац до конца. И думаю, неужели кто-то написал такое серьезное объемное произведение, как концерт, для гитары?